# wordpress json api xmlrpc

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc, json-api

I want to use this Wordpress [JSON API Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) for my Mobile App development but the moment I enable this plugin, the WP site content is open to the world in JSON format.

Is there a way to restrict the JSON API to selected source only? i.e allow the JSON ouput of the WP site only to my domain or IP Address?

I am planning to use the below in the WP's .htaccess

```
Files xmlrpc.php
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 123.456.789
Allow from 321.654.987
Files
```

Will this method restricts the JSON access? Or let me know a better way to allows access to the WP JSON API to only permitted sources.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/150207